# Build qtdeclarative fail on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qtdeclarative

I try to build qtdeclarative from source code but an compilation error occured

> fatal error: QtCore/private/qglobal_p.h: No such file or directory.

Below is some information about my situation

1. OS: Ubuntu 14.04
2. Build Steps

   - Install qt5 library

     > $ sudo apt-get install qt5-default
   - Getting the qtbase source

     > $ mkdir qt; cd qt
     >
     > $ git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qtbase.git
   - Build the qtbase source

     > $ export QTVER=qt5
     >
     > $ export QTDIR=/opt/qt/$QTVER
     >
     > $ export PATH=$QTDIR/bin/:$PATH
     >
     > $ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$QTDIR/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
     >
     > $ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$QTDIR/lib/pkgconfig/:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
     >
     > $ export QT_PLUGIN_PATH=$QTDIR/lib/plugins
     >
     > $cd qtbase
     >
     > $ ./configure -confirm-license -opensource -debug -nomake examples
     >   -nomake tests -make libs -prefix ${QTDIR}
     >
     > $ make
     >
     > $ sudo make install
     >
     > => Build success
   - Getting the qtdeclarative source

     > $ cd ..
     >
     > $ mkdir qtdeclarative; cd qtdeclarative
     >
     > $ git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qtdeclarative.git
   - Build the qtdeclarative source

     > $ qmake
     >
     > $ make

==> ERROR at this step

> fatal error: QtCore/private/qglobal_p.h: No such file or directory.

What did i do wrong or missing something ?

Comment: Which version of Qt ? Once this issue happened in v5.8, see [this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56044)

Comment: @Raptor: i just clone source from git, i'm not sure about the version. Could you teach me how to check it and how to workaround this problem ?

Comment: If you are going to compile you should use the source code and libraries of the same version, when you run: `sudo apt-get install qt5-default` installs version 5.2, and when downloading from git is the last version 5.9, unless you change branch, to have Those problems could be installed declarative with the following command: `sudo apt-get install qtdeclarative5-dev`